# Storefront Changes are not reflecting in Website

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, venia, react-js, store-front

I have done changes in  magento 2.4.5 [ PWA Venia storefront ] frontend. But the changes are not reflecting in website. So I run this below command :

**yarn run build** , but the command is not executing and gives below errors.

```
$ yarn run build:prod
$ yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode production
$ rimraf dist
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storeConfig')
    at /home/ubuntu/glow-frontend/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:73:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async module.exports (/home/ubuntu/glow-frontend/webpack.config.js:61:22)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Do we need to fix above errors or Is there anything else we can do to reflect the changes in frontend after we edit the code files?

Comment: @hello dear , you can try this commands npx update-browserslist-db@latest

Comment: @mohitvamja as this is live site, can i do it ? there will be no problem will happen right ? because we do not have this problem in staging/demo website

Comment: ok dear, but i have't idea in details. when i am get any answer this point. i will inform you.

Comment: @dear, you can take backup db and folder on live site and this backup install your local directory. check and try solved this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151015/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-mohit-vamja).

Comment: Please also check any remaining your site upload file and folder first his check and compare.

Comment: you can see below link try to understand detailed. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated

Comment: @mohitvamja please post an answer, it worked fine